# Action Bar change effect

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to reproduce the Google Keep, Gmail, etc ActionBar change effects.

Like image bellow, when the user select a note or a mail, the action bar changes using its effects.
I would like to do the same.

Any help?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's relatively new ability, called [Contextual action mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB).

Simply put, it's just specific 'context' menu for long-selected item. I think that the link above provides enough information. However, below is some simple example on how to use it:

**main.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:id="@+id/root">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="Do Long Press"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**context_menu.xml**:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
          android:title="close"
          android:showAsAction="always"
          android:id="@+id/close_menu" />
</menu>
```

**MyActivity.java**:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements ActionMode.Callback {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(final View v) {
                startActionMode(MyActivity.this);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(final ActionMode mode, final Menu menu) {
        // Inflate a menu resource providing context menu items
        MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(final ActionMode mode, final Menu menu) {
        // TODO: auto-generated block
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(final ActionMode mode, final MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.close_menu:
                mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(final ActionMode mode) {
        // TODO: auto-generated block
    }
}
```

It looks like the following:

[image]

Execute Long press

[image]

Please note, that `V` item is default one and in context_menu.xml I've provided only `X` item.

Comment: Awesome! I didn't even know how to search this component... Thank you.